# Jedis java.net.socketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

we are using spring redis/jedis to access a redis instance.
we are occasionally getting the "Broken pipe" exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed); nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

when I say occasionally, I mean we only saw it roughly once every month, and it is not predictable which cause a critical issue in our production system.

here is our redis/jedis pool configuration

```
  redis:
    host: *.*.*.*
    port: 6379
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-active: 30
        max-wait: 30000ms
        min-idle: 10
        max-idle: 20
```

we are using spring-boot-starter version `2.2.1.RELEASE` and Jedis `3.1.0`
we only do a simple `GET` to redis: `redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("key");`

e

Comment: can you provide more data? such as the load during the exception, the normal system gets/seconds. this exception is really low level. is there any additional Redis client exception you get?. anyway, I think that good mitigation will be to wrap your call with a retry mechanism, you can check the spring-retry dependency since network issues can happen in a while even if there is no problem in your code.

Comment: What is the "timeout" in your **Redis** (not Jedis, Spring) configuration?